# unique indexes and include statements

Tags: sql, db2

### create unique index

In DB2 UDB I can create an index using the following syntax

```
create unique index I_0004 on TABLENAME (a) INCLUDE (b, c, d);
```

where a, b, c and d are field of the table `TABLENAME`.

In DB2 for os390 this syntax (the `INCLUDE` keyword) is not allowed, so I am creating     the indexes as follows

```
create unique index I_0004 on TABLENAME (a);  
create index I_0005 on TABLENAME (a, b, c, d);
```

Are the two statements above equivalent to the solution with the `INCLUDE` keyword?

### index columns order

And, if I slightly modify the first statement

```
create index I_0005 on TABLENAME (a, b, c, d) ALLOW REVERSE SCANS;
```

is this `ALLOW REVERSE SCANS` equivalent to creating indexes

```
create index I_0005 on TABLENAME (a, b, c, d);  
create index I_0005 on TABLENAME (d, c, b, a);
```

or does it consider also any combination of the given columns (I mean, a,b,c,d; b,c,d,a; c,d,a,b; and so on...)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding the `UNIQUE INDEX`: roughly, yes, a unique index on `(a)` including `(b, c, d)` *is* equivalent to a unique index just on `(a)` plus a non-unique one on `(a, b, c, d)` -- except of course that, internally, the database engine may be able to use less space &c.

Regarding `ALLOW REVERSE SCANS`: no, an index on `(a, b)` that can be reverse-scanned is *not* equivalent to one that can't plus one on `(b, a)` -- rather, an index that can be reverse scanned is equivalent to one that can't plus another on the same columns where each `ASC` becomes a `DESC` and vice versa (and `ASC` is the default when you don't specify).

Note that since DB2 9.1 reverse scans are allowed by default, see http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.db2.udb.rn.doc/doc/c0023548.htm (and, I believe DB2 V8 is now out of support, see http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?rs=71&uid=swg21370360 -- I think V9.5 is the current version).