# Ensuring uniqueness of multiple large URL fields in MS SQL

Tags: indexing, unique-constraint

I have a table with the following definition:

```
CREATE TABLE url_tracker (
    id int not null identity(1, 1),
    active bit not null,
    install_date int not null,
    partner_url nvarchar(512) not null,
    local_url nvarchar(512) not null,
    public_url nvarchar(512) not null,
    primary key(id)
);
```

And I have a requirement that these three URLs always be unique - any individual URL can appear many times, but the combination of the three must be unique (for a given day).

Initially I thought I could do this:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX uniques ON url_tracker 
(install_date, partner_url, local_url, public_url);
```

However this gives me back the warning:

```
Warning! The maximum key length is 900 bytes. The index 'uniques' has maximum
length of 3076 bytes. For some combination of large values, the insert/update
operation will fail.
```

Digging around I learned about the `INCLUDE` argument to `CREATE INDEX`, but according to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/906603/unique-indexes-and-include-statements) converting the command to use `INCLUDE` will not enforce uniqueness on the URLs.

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX uniques ON url_tracker (install_date)
INCLUDE (partner_url, local_url, public_url);
```

How can I enforce uniqueness on several relatively large nvarchar fields?

---

## Resolution

So from the comments and answers and more research I'm concluding I can do this:

```
CREATE TABLE url_tracker (
    id int not null identity(1, 1),
    active bit not null,
    install_date int not null,
    partner_url nvarchar(512) not null,
    local_url nvarchar(512) not null,
    public_url nvarchar(512) not null,
    uniquehash AS HashBytes('SHA1',partner_url+local_url+public_url) PERSISTED,
    primary key(id)
);
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX uniques ON url_tracker (install_date,uniquehash);
```

Thoughts?

Comment: You will probably need to get a hash for each one and compare the hashes.  This will negatively affect performance though.

Comment: @JNK I liked your suggestion, you should post it as an answer

Comment: @JNK I liked that too. You could store the hashes as persisted computed columns though, to lessen the effect. A lower-rent possible solution would be triggers. What version of SQL Server is this?

Comment: Not to judge or anything, but it looks like our good friend @JNK was too late...

Comment: You could also store the URLs in a separate table. Give them a surrogate `id` and just index the combination of the ids

Comment: PS an `INCLUDE` column just "comes along for the ride" to help prevent unnecessary lookups - this is why it can't be used to enforce uniqueness; it is not part of the key.

Comment: @Martin that's a good approach too - it avoids potential hash collisions and also helps storage/performance if the same URLs are used often (just not in the same combination all the time) and compression can help quite a bit too.

Comment: @Martin Smith: that wouldn't work if the URL are updatable. You might end up with semantic duplicates

Comment: @Adrian - It would be possible to code around that and might be worth doing if it could avoid issues with hash collisions but @Aaron - Just noticed the OP is using `nvarchar(512)` so that would still be too big and would just push the problem to the other table.

Comment: @Martin ah yes, and a couple of issues with that - 512 is probably too short, and nvarchar is probably not necessary for URLs (I don't see many URLs with umlauts and far east characters).

Comment: @Martin if the table just has *one* URL column, though, the unique constraint on the primary table could just be `URL_ID1`, `URL_ID2`, and `URL_ID3`... assuming order matters. This would allow the full use of 900 bytes on the unique constraint there. I noticed an added complication, it doesn't need to be unique forever, just for the day... so the date probably has to come into play as well.

Comment: @Aaron - agreed and if many duplicates are expected this could be a good space saving plan anyway but to enforce uniqueness on the table with Urls would still need some sort of hashing scheme unless the datatype is negotiable.

Comment: Why, oh why, is `install_date` an `int`?

Comment: Thank you all for your input, I'd appreciate any feedback on my edit.  For those of you wondering about the URL and date type choices, I know that the types of URLs being inserted will be less than 512, however I need to ensure the URLs are I18N-proof.  The dates are stored as an int for historical reasons.

Comment: I think you're still wasting a *LOT* of spacing by storing every URL in three separate columns, you're also taking big chances that the hashed value of three concatenated URLs will be unique from the hashed value of any other three concatenated URLs. Think about just normal string concat - `'db' + 'foo'` is the same as `'dbf' + 'oo'`... the same kind of collisions are also possible here. Try to step back and think bigger picture - think best solution, not quickest solution.

Comment: That seems unlikely to me given the structure of URLs, but I'll delimit them if you think that's safer.  As for wasted space, the vast majority of these URLs will be unique, this is primarily a necessity to prevent accidental duplicates.

Comment: No, I don't think delimiting them is any safer, that's just another character contributing to all hashes. Did you look at my proposed solution?

Comment: Delimiting prevents the danger you mentioned above, though I'll grant it isn't perfect, it's fine for my use case.  Restructuring the table and codebase isn't terribly desirable, and hashing the URLs together is a good enough solution.  Even if someone were to maliciously construct URLs that collide, they simply wouldn't be inserted in the table.  Given the types of URLs we're trying to track, such a collision would not arise accidentally, and would be easily resolved if it did.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would make a computed column with the [hash](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174415.aspx) of the URLs, then make a unique index/constraint on that.  Consider making the hash a persisted computed column.  It shouldn't have to be recalculated after insertion.

Comment: @dimo414 I think you might need to cast the HASHBYTES to VARBINARY(20) - also if you think there is any way to make the same long string with three different URLs, you may need to delimit them uniquely in some way during the concatenation - i.e. ab123 is ambiguous and could have come from a, b, 123 or ab, 1, 23 or a, b1, 23 etc.

Comment: Considering each starts with http:// I don't imagine that's likely, but I could delimit them with | if you think that's critical.

Answer (score 3):

Following the ideas from the conversation in the comments. Assuming that you can change the datatype of the URL to be `VARCHAR(900)` (or `NVARCHAR(450)` if you really think you need Unicode URLs) and be happy with the limitation on the length of the URL, this solution could work. This also assumes SQL Server 2008 or better. Please, *always* specify what version you're working with; [sql-server](/questions/tagged/sql-server) is not specific enough, since solutions can vary greatly depending on the version.

Setup:

```
USE tempdb;
GO

CREATE TABLE dbo.urls
(
    id INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    url VARCHAR(900) NOT NULL UNIQUE
);

CREATE TABLE dbo.url_tracker 
(
    id INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    active BIT NOT NULL DEFAULT 1,
    install_date DATE NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    partner_url_id INT NOT NULL REFERENCES dbo.urls(id),
    local_url_id   INT NOT NULL REFERENCES dbo.urls(id),
    public_url_id  INT NOT NULL REFERENCES dbo.urls(id),
    CONSTRAINT unique_urls UNIQUE
    (
        install_date,partner_url_id, local_url_id, public_url_id
    )
);
```

Insert some URLs:

```
INSERT dbo.urls(url) VALUES
    ('http://msn.com/'),
    ('http://aol.com/'),
    ('http://yahoo.com/'),
    ('http://google.com/'),
    ('http://gmail.com/'),
    ('http://stackoverflow.com/');
```

Now let's insert some data:

```
-- succeeds:
INSERT dbo.url_tracker(partner_url_id, local_url_id, public_url_id)
VALUES (1,2,3), (2,3,4), (3,4,5), (4,5,6);

-- fails:
INSERT dbo.url_tracker(partner_url_id, local_url_id, public_url_id)
VALUES(1,2,3);
GO

/*
    Msg 2627, Level 14, State 1, Line 3
    Violation of UNIQUE KEY constraint 'unique_urls'. Cannot insert duplicate key 
    in object 'dbo.url_tracker'. The duplicate key value is (2011-09-15, 1, 2, 3).
    The statement has been terminated.
*/

-- succeeds, since it's for a different day:
INSERT dbo.url_tracker(install_date, partner_url_id, local_url_id, public_url_id)
VALUES('2011-09-01',1,2,3);
```

Cleanup:

```
DROP TABLE dbo.url_tracker, dbo.urls;
```

Now, if 900 bytes is not enough, you could change the URL table slightly:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.urls
(
    id INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    url VARCHAR(2048) NOT NULL,
    url_hash AS CONVERT(VARBINARY(32), HASHBYTES('SHA1', url)) PERSISTED,
    CONSTRAINT unique_url UNIQUE(url_hash)
);
```

The rest doesn't have to change. And if you try to insert the same URL twice, you get a similar violation, e.g.

```
INSERT dbo.urls(url) SELECT 'http://www.google.com/';
GO
INSERT dbo.urls(url) SELECT 'http://www.google.com/';
GO

/*
    Msg 2627, Level 14, State 1, Line 1
    Violation of UNIQUE KEY constraint 'unique_url'. Cannot insert duplicate key 
    in object 'dbo.urls'. The duplicate key value is
    (0xd111175e022c19f447895ad6b72ff259552d1b38).
    The statement has been terminated.
*/
```